# Display only my own files/images in media library

Tags: media-library

I just want to let user see only their own files in media library. 
I have 2 questions:

1. it works great on list of media library.

   ```
   add_action('pre_get_posts','users_own_attachments');
    function users_own_attachments( $wp_query_obj ) {

    global $current_user, $pagenow;

   //echo 'pagenow='.$pagenow;

     if( !is_a( $current_user, 'WP_User') )
      return;

     if( 'upload.php' != $pagenow )
       return;

     if( !current_user_can('delete_pages') )
      $wp_query_obj->set('author', $current_user->id );

        return;
   }
   ```

But when you upload files with modal (lightbox) media libray, it shows all of files.

I have an avatar uploader in you profile page (`/wp-admin/profile.php`). when I click upload from media library. it popup a modal and shows all of files even not my own files.

How can I make it the popup modal to show only my files/ pictures?

1. I have an avatar uploader on front-end too. 
   I also need to make it show only own pictures on media modal.

How I could add the page? I did `echo $pagenow;` it's all `index.php`.

I believe that if my 1st question has a solution then it would be fine with front end as well.